# Вопрос к знающим дискретную математику

Tags: алгоритм, математика, дискретная-математика

Можно ли браться за "Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ." Кормена со школьными знаниями математики? Если же нет, посоветуйте вводную литературу, за счет которой можно подготовиться к Кормену.

Comment: Сами подумайте, откуда люди, вас не знающие, могут сказать что-то о ваших способностях?..

Comment: Скачайте эту книжку в интернете и попробуйте

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Алгоритмы - это не всегда математика. Алгоритмы - это больше логика, организация структур данных, оптимальные действия над структурами данных. Конечно же, математика там есть (в книге Кормена) - там есть даже глава "Математические основы". Но в большинстве своем, вам придется читать не про математику, а про организацию данных. Понятное дело, преобразование Фурье будет задействовать сложную матетматику, в которой простому человеку со школьным образованием (да и университетским тоже) будет очень сложно. Но вы ведь хотите почитать эту книгу не из за преобразование Фурье, так ведь? Скорее всего в ваших целях есть задача изучить сортировку, деревья, графы, строки - вот для этого школьного курса математики будет достаточно.

Comment: Да, вы правы. Спасибо за объяснение!